# How can I block Pasting Text in my TextBox (WinRT)?

Tags: windows-8, textbox, windows-runtime, copy-paste

Could you help me please about my problem? I want to block my textbox's pasting and control all characters  are numeric (WinRT).

Comment: @ShivanRaptor :) I want to only disable copy and pasting in my textbox. I think it will be in my textbox keydown event.

Comment: It's fine to filter textbox input, but I would recommend against disabling copy/paste. For one, what if the user wants to paste a number? Blocking that will only serve to annoying the user. The easiest thing, though, is to allow any text, and to display a small error message if the data isn't in the right format.

Comment: User can't be enter non numeric characters in my textbox. So, I have done controlling all text_changed event for checking is character numeric but User can copy paste non numeric characters. So my company wants disabling copy paste from me :) @dlev

Comment: @TuğrulEmreAtalay OK, but I reiterate that preventing copy/paste will mostly serve to annoy your users, you should work to filter the pasted text, rather than disallowing outright.

Comment: @dlev I got it but my bosses don't :)

Answer (score 2):

As of Windows 8.1, you get a "Paste" event that you can subscribe to.  Simply subscribe to it and set the event's `Handled` property to `true` to stop it from reaching the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to prevent <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> & <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> combination, then you have to check that combination in `KeyDown` event. If you get that combination you can clear the clipboard with static method `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.Clear();`

If you don't watch for combination of keys rather then just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, then also you can prevent the copy pasting via keyboards.

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Control)
        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.Clear();
}
```

---

To allow user to enter only numeric data you can use `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` event. Use numeric only regular expression to filter out the characters. Moreover to disable context menu of `TextBox`, `ContextMenuOpening` event will help you. Below is the whole code.

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox Height="50" Width="300" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" ContextMenuOpening="TextBox_ContextMenuOpening_1" />
</Grid>
```

C#

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged_1(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    var IsNumeric = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-9]*$");
    var text = tb.Text;
    if (!IsNumeric.IsMatch(text))
    {
        int CursorIndex = tb.SelectionStart - 1;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(CursorIndex, 1);
        tb.SelectionStart = CursorIndex;
        tb.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}

private void TextBox_ContextMenuOpening_1(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not disable CTRL+C , CTRL+V combinations. @Xyroid

Comment: Thank you again @Xyroid, but it is not working on my project?

Comment: It is not working regularly, sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: I don't think there can be another solution.

Comment: You can block your Ctrl+V, I will paste with my Shift+Insert. ;) This is plain wrong. Tell your boss this can't be done and you would need to implement your own TextBox, which will take you about 3 years to get it right or a few weeks to get a really bad, buggy implementation. :)

Comment: :) :) You are Right Filip, I will talk about it.

Answer (score 1):

**To block the pasting:**
1. Block it from the paste event

```
    txtBox1.Paste += ADDTextBox_Paste;

    void ADDTextBox_Paste(object sender, TextControlPasteEventArgs e) 
    {e.Handled = true;return; }
```

2. Block the the Keydown event for shift + insert and Ctrl + V.

   ```
   void txtBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
       {            
           var shiftState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift);
           var ctrlState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);

           if (((shiftState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down && e.Key == VirtualKey.Insert)
               ||((ctrlState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down && e.Key == VirtualKey.V))
           {
               e.Handled = true; 
               return; 
           }                       
       }
   ```

To Allow only numeric characters you'll have to add this code inside the Keydown event:

```
if ((e.Key < VirtualKey.Number0 || e.Key > VirtualKey.Number9) &&
(e.Key < VirtualKey.NumberPad0 || e.Key > VirtualKey.NumberPad9))
{ e.handled = true; return; }
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer -- painful, as you have to reimplement paste in keyup or down, and more painful b/c **`KeyDown` happens *after* `Paste`**, but effective -- but I'm not sure why you're sniffing for ctrl-v and shift-insert in KeyDown. The paste is already blocked. Those combinations wouldn't appear to do anything afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

USe Shift A to block whole passage. Shift up down or side arrow to block small parts. Right click on blocked passage to 'copy' and paste.